# How can I know which is my Elementary OS version?

Tags: system

I just tried:

```
lsb_release -a
```

But the answer is only about the Ubuntu version (16.04). I have no information about elementary OS version.

The reason I want this information is in order to **upgrade**, or not, to Ubuntu version 18. Is it safe or is it a risk for my **elementary distribution**?

Thank You for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

If

```
lsb_release -a
```

, tells you about Ubuntu 16.04 means you have **elementary OS Loki** installed. Don't know why doesn't say Loki.

---

elementary OS is a distribution on it's own based on Ubuntu, as Ubuntu is based on Debian.

A Ubuntu system can be upgraded to another Ubuntu version because is a rolling release distribution.

elementary OS is not a rolling release distribution, hence you can't upgrade between versions. You have to install from scratch each version. Now if elementary OS were a rolling release distribution, you only could be able to upgrade to another elementary OS version not to a Ubuntu version.

You can experiment with it and try, but you'll be breaking a lot of stuff along.

Is like if you install Ubuntu 18.04 and then upgrade to Debian Sid, I don't believe you'll be able to do it cleanly nor expecting to have a stable system in the process. Is doable yes, but why you installed elementary then?

If you want Ubuntu, then install Ubuntu.

---

### My outputs

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Release:    5.0
Codename:   juno

$ lsb_release -au
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=juno
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 5.0 Juno"

$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
```

Answer (score 3):

The System Settings -> About has detailed information about Elementary OS.
Or you can also click on *Application* from top left corner of your screen and search for *About*.

Comment: On elementary OS 6, it's System Settings -> System

Answer (score 3):

You can check it by clicking the power button from the top right corner of your computer and then 'About This Computer'.
Or you can also click on Application from top left corner of your screen and search for About.
Or check About from settings.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot? I don't have that option and I wan't to check where it should be. I have: User Name with Avatar | User Config | Lock | Log Out | Suspend | Shutdown. (Maybe in other words because mine is in Spanish)

Comment: Yes, please see this [screenshot](https://ibb.co/bJ6rFW6).

Comment: Thanks, is not the same as mine but maybe was becasue i enabled the old indicator icons. Will disable it and check later. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more descriptive tool called `screenfetch` that is working directly from the terminal.

I don't think it is installed by default, so you have to install it first by typing in to the terminal:

```
sudo apt install screenfetch
```

Once installed type `screenfetch`.

About upgrading elementary team has not implemented this option yet so upgrading from Loki to Juno would end up with lots of errors or even system failure. I'd recommend a clean installation.

Comment: https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/blob/master/screenfetch-dev#L543